# Spring boot 3.2 connects to Elasticsearch 7.X

Tags: spring, spring-boot, elasticsearch

The version of elasticsearch server is 7.10.2 which cannot be upgraded.
The application is Spring Boot 3.1 with spring-data-elasticsearch 4.4
Now I am going to upgrade to Spring Boot 3.2, but there are some problems.

My Elasticsearch config is as follow

```
class ElasticSearchConfig(
    private val elasticSearchProperties: ElasticSearchProperties,
): ReactiveElasticsearchConfiguration() {

    override fun clientConfiguration(): ClientConfiguration {

        return ClientConfiguration.builder()
            .connectedTo(elasticSearchProperties.hostAndPort)
            .usingSsl()
            .withConnectTimeout(Duration.ofSeconds(elasticSearchProperties.connectionTimeout))
            .withSocketTimeout(Duration.ofSeconds(elasticSearchProperties.socketTimeout))
            .withBasicAuth(elasticSearchProperties.username, elasticSearchProperties.password)
            .withClientConfigurer(ElasticsearchClients.ElasticsearchClientConfigurationCallback.from { builder ->
                builder
                    .setDefaultHeaders(
                        listOf(BasicHeader(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, ContentType.APPLICATION_JSON)))
                    .addInterceptorLast(HttpResponseInterceptor{ response, _ ->
                        response.addHeader("X-Elastic-Product", "Elasticsearch") })
            })
            .build()
    }
}
```

1. If I keep spring-data-elasticsearch 4.4, it seems that auto configuration of elasticsearch doesn't support this ElasticsearchTransportConfiguration anymore
   the error message is as follow

```
An attempt was made to call a method that does not exist. The attempt was made from the following location:

    org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchClientConfigurations$ElasticsearchTransportConfiguration.restClientTransport(ElasticsearchClientConfigurations.java:94)

The following method did not exist:

    'void co.elastic.clients.transport.rest_client.RestClientTransport.<init>(org.elasticsearch.client.RestClient, co.elastic.clients.json.JsonpMapper, co.elastic.clients.transport.rest_client.RestClientOptions)'

The calling method's class, org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchClientConfigurations$ElasticsearchTransportConfiguration, was loaded from the following location:

    jar:file:/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-autoconfigure/3.2.2/5c407409f8d260a4bc6e173d16fc3b36e6adec21/spring-boot-autoconfigure-3.2.2.jar!/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/elasticsearch/ElasticsearchClientConfigurations$ElasticsearchTransportConfiguration.class

The called method's class, co.elastic.clients.transport.rest_client.RestClientTransport, is available from the following locations:

    jar:file:/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/co.elastic.clients/elasticsearch-java/7.17.9/65d35187ab13f6427d5694a84bd963aa8d0ce964/elasticsearch-java-7.17.9.jar!/co/elastic/clients/transport/rest_client/RestClientTransport.class

The called method's class hierarchy was loaded from the following locations:

    co.elastic.clients.transport.rest_client.RestClientTransport: file:/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/co.elastic.clients/elasticsearch-java/7.17.9/65d35187ab13f6427d5694a84bd963aa8d0ce964/elasticsearch-java-7.17.9.jar


Action:

Correct the classpath of your application so that it contains compatible versions of the classes org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchClientConfigurations$ElasticsearchTransportConfiguration and co.elastic.clients.transport.rest_client.RestClientTransport
```

2. If I upgrade to use spring boot compatible elasticsearch-java which is 8.X, there are runtime error when accessing es

```
org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.UncategorizedElasticsearchException: [es/search] failed: [content_type_header_exception] java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: only one Content-Type header should be provided
    at org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.client.elc.ElasticsearchExceptionTranslator.translateExceptionIfPossible(ElasticsearchExceptionTranslator.java:105) ~[spring-data-elasticsearch-5.2.2.jar:5.2.2]
```

if I remove

```
.setDefaultHeaders(
                        listOf(BasicHeader(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, ContentType.APPLICATION_JSON)))
```

in my ClientConfiguration, another error will pop up

```
org.springframework.dao.DataAccessResourceFailureException: method [POST], host [https://pcp-alpha-ltcp-api.line-ves-dev.com:12000], URI [/settlement-detail/_search?typed_keys=true&search_type=query_then_fetch], status line [HTTP/1.1 406 Not Acceptable]
{"error":"Content-Type header [application/vnd.elasticsearch+json; compatible-with=8] is not supported","status":406}
    at org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.client.elc.ElasticsearchExceptionTranslator.translateExceptionIfPossible(ElasticsearchExceptionTranslator.java:110) ~[spring-data-elasticsearch-5.2.2.jar:5.2.2]
```

I've read this https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/elasticsearch/docs/5.0.6/reference/html/#elasticsearch-migration-guide-4.4-5.0.old-client
But as it mentioned, RestHighLevelClient was removed in spring-data-elasticsearch 5.2 (https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/elasticsearch/reference/migration-guides/migration-guide-5.1-5.2.html)

Is there any suggestions about this? Thanks for any reply.

I would prefer to connect to es server 7 with a es client 8 by auditing header or anything. But all failed. it still shows `only one Content-Type header should be provided` or `Content-Type header [application/vnd.elasticsearch+json; compatible-with=8] is not supported`
I also tried to use spring-data-elasticsearch 4.4, but it is still failed